# Preview Crash issue in swiftUi Xcode 15

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am new to iOS development and I have shifted my project form my m1 mac to intel mac. After that its preview start crashing and Xcode is showing this error to me. Here are the details of the error that Xcode is showing to me.

> LinkDylibError: Failed to build ContentView.swift
>
> Linking failed: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> ld: warning: search path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks-iphonesimulator' not found
> ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'CoreAudioTypes': framework 'CoreAudioTypes' not found
> ld: Undefined symbols:
> *OBJC_CLASS*$_CNContactsUserDefaults, referenced from:
> in GoogleMaps.a
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I want to run my preview working in Xcode on my intel mac.

Comment: Can you run the app in the simulator?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes app is running perfectly on simulator